# Extending Cremona map to the Blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}} U\subseteq \bP^2$ given by 
$$U=\bP^2-\{a,b,c\}$$
where $a=(1:0:0),b=(0:1:0),c=(0:0:1)$.

Let $f:U\to \bP^2$ given by $(x:y:z)\mapsto (yz:xz:xy)$. I want to prove that, despite $f$ cannot be extended to $\bP^2$ (which I have already proven), $f$ can be extended to an isomorphism of $\tilde{\bP}^2$, where
$$\tilde{\bP}^2=\{((x:y:z),f(x,y,z))\mid (x:y:z)\in U\}^-$$
is the closure of the graph of $f$ in $\bP^2\times \bP^2$.

Once it is determined that $f$ can be extended to a morphism of $\tilde{\bP}^2$ I expect that $f$ will be an involution, and thus an isomorphism, but I'm not sure how to extend it.

My main idea was to restrict the projection $\pi_2: \bP^2\times \bP^2\to\bP^2$ to $\tilde{\bP}^2$, and finding an appropiate map $i:\bP^2\to \tilde{\bP}^2$ so that the extension is $i\pi_2$. I'm not sure that's going to work, though.

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745263/cremona-transformation-and-isomorphism) but in the comments I also don't understand what it means for the projections to blow-up the three points. The definition of blow-up of I'm using is also the closure of the graph I mentioned above.

Comment: "the projections blow up the three points" just means that the projections $p_1,p_2:\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^2 \to \mathbb P^2$, when restricted to $\widetilde{\mathbb P^2}$, are the blowup maps (or blow down, if you like).

Comment: @TabesBridges Oh. In the notes I'm using (And also in the section I.4 of Hartshorne's book) they refer to the map $p_1$ to be the blow-up map. What does saying that $p_2$ is the blow-up map mean? Does it mean that it behaves the same as $p_1$? I'm not sure if "being the blow-up maps" means more than that in some terminology I'm not familiar with (Since most of the sources I've read approach to the blow-up topic in a different way).

But how can I use that to build the extension of $f$?

Comment: So in the particular case of the Cremona transformation (not for general blowups), the map $p_2$ is also the blowup of three points, but not the *same* three points (since the target of the rational map is not the same $\mathbb P^2$). When you blow up the three points to obtain $p_1$ (visualize a triangle joining the points) the lines between the points are separated, but now joined by $3$ exceptional curves (visualize a hexagon). Since blowing up a point reduces self-intersection by $1$, the proper transforms of the three initial lines are now $(-1)$-curves...

Comment: ...which means they can be contracted. The images of the exceptional curves under this contraction are now a triangle joining the three points that are the images of the $(-1)$-curves. In other words, the Cremona map takes three points and the lines between them, and transforms this configuration into three lines and the points at which they meet (i.e. the points become lines and the lines become points).

Comment: @TabesBridges Oh. I hadn't seen it that way and I think I'm seeing it now. But I'm not sure $p_2$ is the blow-up of three points.

I mean, the points in the image of the Cremona map consists on all the points $(a:b:c)$ such that all of their coordinates are nonzero or two of their coordinates are zero. So in the graph, we're omitting three lines, not three points (The lines $(x:y:0),(0:y:z),(x:0:z)$ joining $a,b,c$). It would seem to be the blow-up at these three lines.

Comment: I've been thinking for a while and it seems too trivial so I think I must be wrong. Since the second projection $p_2$ is a way of extending $f$ to a map from $\tilde{\mathbb{P}^2}$, doesn't the identity map $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}^2\to \tilde{\mathbb{P}}^2$,  sort of extend $f$, too?

Comment: The line $(x:y:0)$ maps to the point $(0:0:1)$ since the first two coordinates have a factor of $z$, so the map is defined on all but two points of each line. And the identity map on the blowup does not extend $f$ since it doesn't agree with the formula for $f$; for instance, $(1:2:3) \mapsto (6:3:2)$, and these are not equivalent points.

Comment: What about the map induced by both projections, $(p_2,p_1)$?

Comment: That's the embedding of the blowup *as* the graph of the rational map.